# Converting String style from Arduino to C common style

Tags: c, string, arduino

I have the following code

```
void loop() {
  String outMessage = "";  // String to hold input

  while (Serial.available() > 0) {  // check if at least one char is available
    char inChar = Serial.read();
    outMessage.concat(inChar);  // add Chars to outMessage (concatenate)
  }

  if (outMessage != "") {
    Serial.println("Sent:  " + outMessage); // see in Serial Monitor
    Serial1.write(outMessage); // Send to the other Arduino
  }
```

and I want to write it in the common C language.

The Arduino String class, part of the core as of version 0019, allows us to use and manipulate strings of text in more complex ways than character arrays do.

I don't know what way is better for programming. The only thing I know is that `String` takes a lot of memory. Any sugestion?

Comment: If you just want to use C, use char*

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as "the Arduino language". Arduinos (well, rather the AVRs inside) are programmed using C, C++ or assembler, and the Arduino core library provides some C functions (along with AVR-libc) and C++ classes for common tasks. What you are **actually** trying to do here is transforming your code from C++ to C.

Specifically, in C, strings are 0-terminated arrays of `char`, so you could do something like this:

```
char welcome[] = "Hello world!";
```

[Moar...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_string_handling)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be too hard.  I love working with char arrays, because really, it isn't difficult at all.  To concat two char arrays though, you'll have to know their sizes, and you'll have to make a 3rd buffer that is the size of the first char array + second char array.  The only problem with this is finding the size.  This can be done with a simple struct:

```
 typedef struct String{
    int size;
    char * chararray;

 }String;
```

Then you'll have to malloc the chararray with the size and populate the integer value.

The rest is pretty simple after that.

Comment: Thats it. I want something with variable size.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you want somethign with variable size?  Did I explain correctly?

Comment: I want something like protocols, for instance the string will be: [3bytes][variable lenght][3bytes]. Variable is for data (text)

Comment: You can do this with malloc and calloc.  If you have 3 bytes on the end though, you'll have to store them, then extend the char array with calloc, then copy the last 3 bytes back into the returned calloc space.  You'll have to still keep track of size, that's why I'm saying it should be easier with a struct.

Comment: Can I use Arduino String and put all this information in the same string? and then I can manipulate the string and take only the data I want?